# Why can I not implement inheritance like this?

Tags: python, python-2.7

To begin with, I know there is a right way to implement inheritance like this:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, last_name, eye_color):
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.eye_color = eye_color

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, last_name, eye_color, number_of_toys):
        Parent.__init__(self, last_name, eye_color)
        self.number_of_toys = number_of_toys

miley_cyrus = Child("Cyrus", "Blue", 5)
print(miley_cyrus.last_name)
print(miley_cyrus.number_of_toys)
```

When I run the piece of code, there is the result that

```
Cyrus
5
```

However when I change the 7th line into :

```
self = Parent(last_name, eye_color)
```

and the the code has become:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, last_name, eye_color):
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.eye_color = eye_color

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, last_name, eye_color, number_of_toys):
        self = Parent(last_name, eye_color)
        self.number_of_toys = number_of_toys

miley_cyrus = Child("Cyrus", "Blue", 5)
print(miley_cyrus.last_name)
print(miley_cyrus.number_of_toys)
```

, I run the piece of code, there is an error indicates that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Echo/Documents/IT/Udacity/python/7.Inheritance/inherentance.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(miley_cyrus.last_name)
AttributeError: Child instance has no attribute 'last_name'
```

What's wrong with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `self = Parent` ? you want parent object for self ?

Comment: try this self.obj = Parent(last_name, eye_color)

Comment: Note that for unrelated reasons it's best in Python to inherit `object` rather than nothing (`class Parent(object):`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are doing but you can get your expected result this way.

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, last_name, eye_color):
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.eye_color = eye_color

class Child(Parent):
     def __init__(self, last_name, eye_color, number_of_toys):
        self.obj = Parent(last_name, eye_color)
        self.number_of_toys = number_of_toys

miley_cyrus = Child("Cyrus", "Blue", 5)
print(miley_cyrus.obj.last_name)
print(miley_cyrus.number_of_toys)
```

`self = Parent` should be `self.some_variable = Parent`

Comment: That's Good one..!

Comment: Note: in this case, there's no need to inherit `Parent` at all. Just do plain-old `class Child(object):`

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers to this point didn't really get to the actual problem. In my interpretation, you think, that `self` is some sort of context which you could change manually.

Are you aware, that `self` really is the instance you are creating? Reassigning it would not only be confusing, it would be wrong - eventough assigning to parameters isn't possible.

You can execute this piece of code which shows you, that you are trying to mutate `miley_cyrus` into a `Parent` inside of the `Child` initializer:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, last_name, eye_color):
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.eye_color = eye_color

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, last_name, eye_color, number_of_toys):
        # hex(id(self)) -> 0x7fe2325a7da0
        self.number_of_toys = number_of_toys

miley_cyrus = Child("Cyrus", "Blue", 5) # hex(id(miley_cyrus)) -> 0x7fe2325a7da0
```

Also I think that the term *initializer* is very important here, because you could get confused with conventional languages. Python has a separate magic method which is responsible for actually creating the object (`__new__`). At the time `__init__` is called - you are already operating on the instantiated object. That's why `__new__` takes a class-object rather than `self`.